# Why <HTMLAudioElement> has no method 'set'

Tags: backbone.js, dom-events, html5-audio

My code is below, when I run it, it shows error - `<HTMLAudioElement>` has no method 'set'.
Why it''s happening? I've bound my functions to model, but it seems to work wrongly:

```
var Player = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){         
        _.bind(this.ontimeupdate, this);
        _.bind(this.onprogress, this);
    },      
    setAudio: function(ogglink, mp3link, ontimeupdate){
        var el = document.createElement("audio");           
        el.addEventListener('timeupdate', this.ontimeupdate);
        this.audiotag = el;
    },      
    ontimeupdate: function() {
        this.set("curtime", this.currentTime);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `bindAll` (which you should be using as you make several binds), `bind` only [returns the binded function](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) (equivalent to ECMA's `bind` method). So...

```
this.ontimeupdate = _.bind(this.ontimeupdate, this);
this.onprogress = _.bind(this.onprogress, this);
```

Or

```
_.bindAll(this);
```

Or

```
_.bindAll(this, 'ontimeupdate', 'onprogress');
```

Comment: this way kills errors, but player works wrong now.
when i click on play, song start playing only on a 3 time

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding those methods to `this` (your Player instance) then your `ontimeupdate` method should probably look more like this:

```
ontimeupdate: function() {
    this.set("curtime", this.audiotag.currentTime);
}
```

Comment: i've tried this way before asking, problem is that 'this' is not a player instance, it's a content of a player's variable 'audiotag'

Comment: You need to actually bind the instance to those methods like @Loamhoof said: `_.bindAll(this, 'ontimeupdate', 'onprogress')`. Then it will work.